# Inline Variable Declaration Failing to Build

Tags: c#

On a project I took over, there was this extension method:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseDateTime(this string val)
{
    DateTime date;
    return DateTime.TryParse(val, out date) ? date : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

Personally, I like to use inline variable declarations when possible so I updated this method to:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseDateTime(this string val)
{
    return DateTime.TryParse(val, out DateTime date) ? date : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

This project is in VS 2017 and the Error list shows **no** errors, but the project fails to build.  When I check the output window, I see an error is occurring in this method with the message:

*2>C:...\Extensions.cs(35,56,35,60): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected*

I am not clear on what this error is referring to since this error only appears when I actually try to build.  I also tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding but the error persists.  Any insight into the cause of this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Did you set the language version in the project settings to C#7.0 or newer?

Comment: That syntax is not backwards compatible, of course. This is a trivial change that is not going to make any difference, though.

Comment: @UnholySheep  I have it set to "C# latest major version (default)" and if expand the dropdown it shows I have up to C#7.3.